# Android error app crash error when firebase message sent

Tags: java, android, firebase, messaging

My FireBaseMessaging.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    //private static final String TAG = "AbsWorkoutFCM";
    private static final String TAG = "faceenhancer";
    //String app_banner_url, app_package_name;
    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        String app_banner_url= null, app_package_name = null;
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            if (data.containsKey(APP_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
                app_package_name = data.get(APP_PACKAGE_NAME);
                app_banner_url = data.get(APP_BANNER_URL);
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        //String Icon = remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon();

        sendNotification(app_package_name, app_banner_url, body, title);
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param package_name FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String package_name, String app_banner_url, String body, String title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(APP_PACKAGE_NAME, package_name);
        intent.putExtra(APP_BANNER_URL, app_banner_url);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)//ic_stat_ic_notification
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.fcm_faceenhancer)//tatto_icon
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And service in Manifest file as

```
  <service           
    > android:name="com.faceenhancer.android.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    >                 android:enabled="true"
    >                 android:exported="true">
    >                 <intent-filter>
    >                     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    >                 </intent-filter>
    </service
```

> 

When  sent notification message from console getting this exception in logcat..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOJXI.png

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.<init> (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.0.1:3)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.<init> (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.0.1:1)
  at com.faceenhancer.android.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.<init> (MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:26)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService (AppComponentFactory.java:129)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService (CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:4299)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:252)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2018)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:250)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7886)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:970)
```

This error appeared when notification is sent from firebase console and app crashed

Please help after sending message from console getting

Comment: What's the code that produces that crash?

Comment: Please check the code i have edited